# PTIJ: May one interrupt the Amidah to talk to God?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've been told that when one says the *amidah*, one should imagine that he is addressing the King of Kings, directly.

What happens if in the middle of the *amidah*, someone's cell phone rings and upon noticing the caller ID, it says "God"? Maybe it really is God calling on the phone answering one's prayers? Is one allowed to answer the call in the middle of the *amidah*? Wouldn't a direct phone conversation with God have higher priority over the Amidah where you can't hear God's voice? I would also think that speaking to God over the phone, would be more intimate, and you can get a better sense that God is listening to you knowing he's on the phone.

Or, do we say that since we are already "talking" to God in the Amidah, talking to him on the phone is like "stereo" and is confusing? What if God has something important to tell the person? Is it fair to have God leave you a voice message (assuming that he will)?

**Note:** Shulchan Aruch O.C. 104:1 says that one may not interrupt the *amidah* to address a Jewish King. Well, God is a king. However,since God is the king of all humanity, it may beg the question if we could specifically consider God, himself, "Jewish" vs. "multi-religional".

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: When I saw the title I thought: is the premise that in amidah we spend the time thinking about all the stuff we need to do but occasionally we may need to talk to Hashem, and is that allowed (after all, this is the time for thinking about other stuff, and not actually praying...)? But no, different direction.

Comment: Surely He would show up in your contacts as G-d, not God. Clearly it's a fake that's calling.

Comment: It is not a direct answer but do not take video calls as per Ki Tisa **וַיֹּ֕אמֶר לֹ֥א תוּכַ֖ל לִרְאֹ֣ת אֶת־פָּנָ֑י כִּ֛י לֹֽא־יִרְאַ֥נִי הָאָדָ֖ם וָחָֽי׃** *But,” He said, “you cannot see My face, for man may not see Me and live.”*

Comment: @DonielF I would think the opposite. God surely refers to himself by his full actual "name", with actual correct pronunciation and spelling. It's we that can't do it out of respect to his holiness. But God can do whatever in God's name he wishes.

Comment: He would never be writing his name in English. So make sure you never use one with hebrew letters.

Answer (score 3):

## No.  But do call Him back right away.

I looked up a few sources, and they pointed me to the Gemara, *Berachot* 30b and 32b.  Ber. 30b says that one may not interrupt his Amidah even to respond to a king; 32b elaborates that this applies only with respect to a Jewish monarch, who should recognize that the delay is due to prayer.

Accordingly the Supreme Sovereign, B"H, will know that He has called you while you were davening, and He will leave a callback number.  You should conclude your Amidah swiftly, without any personal petitions during *Shema Koleinu*.  After you complete your Amidah (and if appropriate the *Shaliach Tzibbur* has completed the Kedusha) immediately and quietly step out of the room and return the call.  Any personal petitions that you skipped during prayer may be presented directly, at the end of the call.

The stringent treat a phone call much like a knock at the door -- defer any reply until after the Amidah.

Much like a knock at the door, though, it is permissible to take the call (stepping out of the room of course) if ignoring it would disrupt your *kavanah*.  In this case, after completing the call, one's *kavanah* would be thoroughly all over the place, so it is necessary to restart the Amidah if possible.  (Divine manifestations are known to scramble the senses.  If your senses are so scrambled that you are unable to recite the prayers from the *siddur*, it is far preferable to say a brief personal prayer *b'lev* than to attempt to smell or taste the words in the book.)

Edited to address comment:  If answering the Divine call would cause the group to drop below a *minyan*, it is proper to remain with the community through the end of the service, or at least until someone else shows up.  Glorify Him through the community of the faithful, &c.

Comment: Clever answer. One caveat, that you may wish to edit in. Can I step out of the room if that means there's no minyan available for Torah reading, especially if I have a long conversation with God?

Comment: I am sure he is always busy and you will never be able to get hold him if you call him back. and abraham only told him to go when he got visitors because he knew he would come back. so no choice you can speak now

Comment: @interested: I did include the option to take the call immediately.  Which, as I noted, would constitute an interruption, necessitating restarting the Amidah if capable.